# My app was rejected becasue In App Purchase does not have binary

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I submitted an App with an In App Purchase.  The app is free and In App Purchase unleashes some of the features already programmed by setting a flag in user defaults.
However, my app was just rejected because they said they need a binary update for In App Purchase.  There is no binary for it, it is just a flag.
How can I resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: you may also ask the review team - my experience is very positive having to resolve similar issues...

Comment: Thanks.  They did respond with proper instructions and it went through.  My app is "Stock Trading Partner".  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App store guys responded to my comments promptly and everything is fine now.  My app is in the app store now.
Thanks for all the help I got from this site.

Comment: Now would you mind sharing with us what the review team said and how you fixed/worked around the issue?

Comment: They gave me an step by step instruction to incorporate in-app.  When I did that, it did not ask for any binary.  I think they may have changed a flag or something.